# external style sheet and @media print

Tags: css

I am seeing inconsistent results when using print stylesheets and @media print.
When should I use either one or both?

print.css

```
#rptViewer 
{
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#printReport
{
     visibility: visible;
                height: 100%;
                font: small;
                background: #eee;
                position: relative;
                margin-left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                display: table;
                margin: 0 auto;
                overflow-x:scroll;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow:visible !important;
                border : solid 2px;
}
html, body
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

This external linking of css print stylesheet cuts of the report and just shows a scroll bar or image and does not print the entire page.  If I inclued @media print in the aspx page, it prints it correctly(does not cut off the report and no image like scrollbars). What is the difference between the two approaces. Also does @media print work in all versions of IE. The client uses IE 8.

If i comment out the style type =text/css and @media print chunk, its all  messed up and prints only half of the page. 
I am using window.print()

This is how the Aspx page looks this

```
 <link href="Style/print.css"  type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" media="print" />
<style type="text/css">
        @media print
        {
           html, body
            {
                height: 100%;
                width:100%;
            }

            #rptViewer
            {
                display: none;
                visibility: hidden;
            }


            #printReport
            {
                visibility: visible;
                height: 100%;
                font: small;
                background: #eee;
                position: relative;
                margin-left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                display: table;
                margin: 0 auto;
                overflow-x:scroll;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow:visible !important;
                border : solid 2px;
            }

            body
            {
                background: white;
                font-size: 12pt;
                margin: 0px;

            }
        }

    </style>
```

There are 2 approaches here: one is the external css and the other is @media print.
If I include the @media print in the aspx file, it prints like this and does not cut off the report.

Comment: "Also does @media print work in all versions of IE." Yes, pretty much.